# Create database spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm using spark 2.4.4 with AWS glue catalog.

In my spark job, I need to create a database in glue if it doesn't exist. I'm using the following statement in spark sql to do so.

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s".format(hiveDatabase));
```

It works as expected in `spark-shell`, a database gets create in Glue.
But when I run the same piece of code using `spark-submit`, then the database is not created. Is there a commit/flush that I need to do when using spark-submit?

**EDIT**
I'm getting different results for `show databases` in `spark-shell` and `spark-submit`:

```
+---------------------+
|databaseName         |
+---------------------+
|all                  |
|default              |
|hive-db              |
|navi-database-account|
|navi-par             |
|testdb               |
+---------------------+


+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|default     |
+------------+
```

Looks like spark-submit is creating the DB somewhere, but not in glue.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Do you use AWS EMR to run Spark Jobs ? Which deploy mode is used for spark-submit, client or cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add following config:

```
("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive")
```